# Primefaces How can I hide empty datalist items on IE8?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

This is my style work :

```
     .ui-datalist-item:empty {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

it used to work for Chrome but now on IE8 it's not responding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not applicable as IE8 does not recognize that this data list item is empty so I worked arround it in JQuery :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ui-datalist-item').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

what may also help is to use this class (e.g. for `<p:outputPanel>`)

```
.ui-datalist-empty-message {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```